# Swift 3 - Rotation not working properly

Tags: ios, swift3

The situation is like this:

1. If the apps in landscape mode - display an image_1
2. If the apps in portrait mode - display an image_2

I have tried other tutorials but still facing a problem.

```
//  MARK:- Orientation
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
       let endpoint = URL(string: "http://xx.xx.x.xx")
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: endpoint!)
                    img_card_logo.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    img_card_logo.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
                    img_card_logo.backgroundColor = .black

                    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }

                print("Landscape Mode")
    } else {
         let endpoint = URL(string: "http://xx.xx.x.xx")
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: endpoint!)
                img_card_logo.image = UIImage(data: data)

                self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

            print("Potrait Mode")
    }
}
```

I need to rotate the emulator multiple times then only the image is appear, but the print statement working fine.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: why did written this line                 img_card_logo.image = UIImage(data: data)
 in portraint while you does not required ?

Comment: @KKRocks image of potrait and landscape was different. Need to load from different URL.

Comment: then i confused on your statement **If the apps in portrait mode - not display an image**

Comment: @KKRocks, sory my mistakes.

Comment: then what issue faced ?

Comment: @KKRocks, if the device in landscape mode, I want image_2 appear and image_1 disappear, and then if the device in portrait mode, I want image_1 appear and image_2 disappear.

Comment: yes i understood but what is the problem with above code ?

Comment: @KKRocks When I test on emulator, the image_2 not appear for first time but the print statement is printed ("Landscape Mode"). When it rotate (Landscape Mode) for second time, then only the image_2 is appear. Why is that happen ?

Comment: change  this line in landscape mode :                     self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

Comment: @KKRocks done. But still same.

Comment: The content you get via URL is coming on another thread, so if you you want to receive the image by url, you should somehow control the request and using a callback, assign the image on the main thread.

Comment: @SaidHasanein How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I sugget you to download both images once you've loaded the view controller cause firing a request while your view will transition to size is kind of tricky and actually a bad approach.

To request images use either Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

or create your own request:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
           (data, response, error) in
           guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("There was an error!")
                return
            }
            //Add operation to Main Thread queue
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                image_view.image = image
            })
        }
task.resume()
```

Using the above code, you could create two in class variables (eg. image1, image2), download images on viewDidLoad, then use them in viewWillTransitionToSize.

Comment: still same thing.